# cannot complete qt with clang_complete

Tags: c++, qt, vim, clang, code-completion

I am trying to use [clang_complete](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete) as a vim C++ completion.
I must note that I am using [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) too.
I sourced the vimball provided for clang-pathogen and put everything in my `~/.vim/bundle/Clang_complete` directory and everything worked as magic...
My `STL` and `Boost` completion works fine.

Here is what I did:

---

1/create a `test_qt.cpp` file

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication app(argc, argv);
QWidget window;
window.resize(250, 150);

window.setWindowTitle("Simple example");
window.show();
return app.exec();
}
```

---

2/ran `qmake -project`

---

3/ran `qmake -o Makefile testFiles.pro`

---

4/ran `make`

```
 make
 g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_WEBKIT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -I. -o test_qt.o test_qt.cpp
 g++ -m64 -Wl,-O1 -o testFiles test_qt.o    -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread
```

---

5/ ran `./testFiles` and everything went fine, I got a stupid window...

So I don't understand why I cannot get qt completion...
My `Makefile` is correctly generated, what should I do ?
I tried to run

```
statquant@euclide:~/.vim/testFiles$ make CC= '~/.vim/bundle/Clang_Complete-Pathogen/bin/cc_args.py' CXX='~/.vim/bundle/Clang_Complete-Pathogen/bin/cc_args.py'
```

But got :

```
make: Nothing to be done for `/home/statquant/.vim/bundle/Clang_Complete-Pathogen/bin/cc_args.py'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have redundant whitespace in your command:

```
make CC=<HERE>'~/.vim/bundle/Clang_Complete-Pathogen/bin/cc_args.py' CXX='~/.vim/bundle/Clang_Complete-Pathogen/bin/cc_args.py'
```

Your should remove it. Secondly your command is wrong - you didn't specify compilers. To summarize, it should look like this:

```
make CC='~/.vim/bundle/Clang_Complete-Pathogen/bin/cc_args.py gcc' CXX='~/.vim/bundle/Clang_Complete-Pathogen/bin/cc_args.py g++' -B
```

This is because, essentially, `cc_args.py` will act as a wrapper (for compiler executable) to record which `-I`, `-D`, and other flags are passed during compilation of your project. It will then cleverly forward all flags to the compiler itself - so the project is built correctly. Invoke `:h clang_complete-cc_args` and see `cc_args.py` for better understanding - it is trivial.

**NOTE:** `-B` flag is used to force `make` to build, regardless of whether your current build is up -to-date or not. This way, `.clang_complete` file is always up-to-date.

Finally, if after all it still does not work, then it means that `qmake` generates `makefile` which does not respect `CC` and `CXX` environment variables, but rather hard-coded paths of compiler executables. I don't remember if this is the case with `qmake`, but once again, if all fails, then this is the only reason - which you can easily check by inspecting the generated `makefile`.

Good luck.

Comment: It worked !just had to chmod +x the python script !
Many thanks